# How To Active Bootstrap Tab after Button Click in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am working in asp.net and i use twitter bootstrap plugins. In my form i use a Tab. There are two option in Tab. **#1** is **Map** and **#2** is **Address**. Basically i submit a form and save the data into database when data is save then i want saved data shown in **#2** Tab (**Address Tab**). I found many article in stackoverflow related it, but i not achieve this.

**Code:-ASP**

```
            <div class="Map-Panel">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#divMap">Map</a></li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#divAddress">Address</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div id="divMap" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                        <div id="geomap" style="width: 100%; height: 450px;">
                            <p>Loading Please Wait...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="divAddress" class="tab-pane fade">
                        <asp:DataList ID="dlAddress" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" RepeatColumns="1" Width="100%">
                        </asp:DataList>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**Code:-Javascript**

```
$('#<%= btnSave.ClientID %>').click(function () {
            $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});
```

If i use HTML submit button then i able to active other tab but through this i can't save my data into database. So help me.

Answer (score 1):

Did yout tried to wrap both tabs inside the same form?
This way will send all data from both tabs to your server side script.

Comment: i use only one form for all

Comment: can you show the server side code that is called in your save action?